# Can I pass arguments to a function in monkeypatch.setattr for a function used multiple times in one view?

Tags: flask, pytest, monkeypatching

My web application makes API calls to Spotify. In one of my Flask views I use the same method with different endpoints. Specifically:

```
sh = SpotifyHelper()
...
@bp.route('/profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def profile():
...
    profile = sh.get_data(header, 'profile_endpoint')
    ...
    playlist = sh.get_data(header, 'playlist_endpoint')
    ...
    # There are 3 more like this to different endpoints -- history, top_artists, top_tracks
    ...
    return render_template(
        'profile.html',
        playlists=playlists['items'],
        history=history['items'],
        ...
        )
```

I do not want to make an API call during testing so I wrote a mock.json that replaces the JSON response from the API. I have done this successfully when the method is only used once per view:

```
class MockResponse:
@staticmethod
def profile_response():
    with open(path + '/music_app/static/JSON/mock.json') as f:
        response = json.load(f)
    return response

@pytest.fixture
def mock_profile(monkeypatch):
    def mock_json(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse.profile_response()

    monkeypatch.setattr(sh, "get_data", mock_json)
```

My problem is that I need to call `get_data` to different endpoints with different responses. My mock.json is written:

```
{'playlists': {'items': [# List of playlist data]},
 'history': {'items': [# List of playlist data]},
  ...
```

So for each API endpoint I need something like

```
playlists = mock_json['playlists']
history = mock_json['history']
```

I can write `mock_playlists()`, `mock_history()`, etc., but how do I write a monkeypatch for each? Is there some way to pass the endpoint argument to `monkeypatch.setattr(sh, "get_data", mock_???)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock



#other code...

mocked_response = MagicMock(side_effect=[
    # write it in the order of calls you need
    profile_responce_1, profile_response_2 ... profile_response_n
])

monkeypatch.setattr(sh, "get_data", mocked_response)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works? This can help future readers learn and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.

Comment: There's really nothing to explain: side_effect gets iterable and returns the next item (response in our case) whenever mock gets called. We could write a function with iterator but this approach is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

**Example mock a function with argument**

```
"""my_module.py"""

def original_func(arg1, arg2):
    print(f'original func, arg1: {arg1} and arg2 {arg2}')

def use_original_func():
    arg1 = "modified_arg1_by_use_original_func"
    arg2 = "modified_arg2_by_use_original_func"
    original_func(arg1, arg2)


"""mock_demo.py"""

import pytest

import my_module
@pytest.fixture
def mock_original_func(monkeypatch):
    def mock_query(arg1, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Mocking original_func")
        print(arg1, "mocked_arg2")

    monkeypatch.setattr(my_module, 'original_func', mock_query)


def test_use_original_func(mock_original_func):
    my_module.use_original_func()

 ### Output
 ============================= test session starts 
 ==============================
 collecting ... collected 1 item

 mock_demo.py::test_use_original_func PASSED                              
 [100%]Mocking original_func
 modified_arg1_by_use_original_func mocked_arg2


 ============================== 1 passed in 0.01s 
 ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```